# How can I find out which software is occupying the F2 functionality of my keyboard?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I have a copy of Windows 7 64 bit installed on my Laptop. Everything is all right, but recently I have installed some software and now my F2 key doesn't work.

I'm wondering what solution you guys recommend to me to find out which software is occupying F2 functionality (rename) of the keyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would toss on [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and take a look at what jumped onto the list when you hit F2.

Might be clunky, but it beats registry-spelunking!

Comment: How do you use procmon to do this exactly?

Comment: Start it up, start tracking, qucikly hit F2 and stop tracking. Then you get to sort through all the results. Simple, but not necessarily easy the first few times.

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but no luck.  There are so many events to filter out, and I don't even know what I am looking for.  I have posted a question about the problem I am experiencing.